# Merging of data columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge tables based on a key that is common to them using pandas and I am constantly getting the error :

> KeyError: 'Host Key of Allocated Locations'

Table one has data: highlighted value is the 'Host Key of Allocated Locations'. Also, it has duplicate values which I want to have as they will be needed in further analysis.
[image]

Table 2: highlighted value is the PK key
[image]

`df3 = pd.merge(timetable_2020_df, joined_uom_space_df, on='Host Key of Allocated Locations', how='left')`

I tried but I cannot understand what the issue is.

duplicate data is :

[image]

Comment: Well your column in right table is called PK so it doesn't know about `'Host Key of Allocated Locations',` you have to tell pandas that probably just modify your code to `df3 = pd.merge(timetable_2020_df, joined_uom_space_df, left_on='Host Key of Allocated Locations', right_on='PK', how='left')`

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

```KeyError: 'PK'```

df3 = pd.merge(joined_uom_space_df,timetable_2020_df, left_on='PK', right_on='Host Key of Allocated Locations', how='right')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on` keyword only works when you have the same named column in *both* dataframes. Your `right` dataframe does not have the 'Host...' column, hence a keyerror is being raised.

You will need to use `left_on` and `right_on` keywords to specify the joining columns in your left and right dataframes.

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

```KeyError: 'PK'```

df3 = pd.merge(joined_uom_space_df,timetable_2020_df, left_on='PK', right_on='Host Key of Allocated Locations', how='right')

Comment: your solution solved it. I had changed the 'PK' column name to a different name and didn't update that in the code